# Deployment issue : Lightning Quick Actions for Component Bundles

Tags: salesforce, lightning

Trying to deploy lightning component bundles, the lightning components are referenced on quick actions created and placed on account layout.

When I am trying to deploy the lightning component bundles, its threwing following deployment issues :
[image]

I have tried so many ways to fix the issues by adding/removing required attributes in lightning components, also tried to add/remove default values on attributes, but still has the same issue. Also tried to change the version on component from 38.0 to 37.0, but still no luck.

Can anyone help me on this? Thanks in Advance!!

Thanks,
​Tarun

Answer (score 0):

This is the workaround fixed my issue :

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000DaazQAC